# Meteor: Difference between normal build and debug build

Tags: android, meteor, mobile, apk

One of the options to build a Meteor app is --debug.
In the command line help for **Meteor build**, it only says that with the **--debug** option, code isn't minified:

```
 --debug             Build in debug mode (don't minify, etc).
```

and I was wondering what other differences there are between the normal build mode and build with debug.

I'm wondering too what are the differences between the apk file generated with debug mode (called debug.apk ) and normal mode (called release-unsigned.apk), because the apk from the debug mode is working for me and the other have some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the documentation:

> The buildTypes element controls how to build and package your app. By
>   default, the build system defines two build types: debug and release.
>   The debug build type includes debugging symbols and is signed with the
>   debug key. The release build type is not signed by default.

Debug builds also (by default) skip optimisations like minification or shrinking resources, to speed up development, whereas release builds will perform these steps to streamline builds that will be published for consumers.

[Configuring Gradle Builds](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)

Comment: for my case, debug build worked fine, but release didn't. What did go wrong?
And is it safe to publish debug apk?

Comment: No, the Play Store won't even accept a debuggable APK when you try to publish it. And you need to be much more specific about what didn't work. Post new questions with specific information about the problems with the release build.

Comment: @younessofiane there must be some error in your js files and hence it gives an error in release. Maybe you missed a comma between functions